# Jquery button Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, typeerror

I am writing a piece of code which will show button label of all jquery buttons having class="Short"

I am using the following code:-

```
$('.Short').button();
var all_short_btns = $(".Short");
for(i=0; i< all_short_btns.length; i++){
   alert(all_short_btns[i].button( "option", "label" ));
}
```

Html is:

```
<button class="Short">Label1</button>
<button class="Short">Label2</button>
<button class="Short">Label3</button>
<button class="Short">Label4</button>
<button class="Short">Label5</button>
<button class="Short">Label6</button>
```

I am getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'button'

My Question is how to get label for each button element ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using the wrong method, use `.eq(i)` to get the specific item and then get the text by calling `.html()`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/25eWd/)

```
var all_short_btns = $(".Short");
for(i=0; i< all_short_btns.length; i++){
    alert(all_short_btns.eq(i).html());
}
```

Alternatively you could use `$.each()` but it's quite a bit slower than the native `for` loop.

```
var all_short_btns = $(".Short");
$.each(all_short_buttons, function (i, item) {
    alert(item.html());
});
```

### Update

Since the OP was using jQuery UI `.html()` would print out the `<span>` that is automatically generated and wraps the content. The error is occurring because you are using `[i]` which gets the raw JavaScript object when we need the jQuery object. `.eq()` gets the jQuery object at that index.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/RqupB/)

```
all_short_btns.eq(i).button("option", "label")
```

Comment: The OP uses jQuery UI. Using `.button( "option", "label" )` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Despite this being accepted, I just noticed that `.html` is *not* a good solution here, since jQuery adds additional elements to the button element. See http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/YR6cA/.

Comment: Yes I agree but here no one had given answer with .button( "option", "label" ) instead of me. and I cannot accept my answer. But its true I came to know the .eq(i) trick from this answer. So I gave this a tick.

Comment: I updated my answer with the reason for this. FYI, try to use `items.eq(i)` instead of `$(items[i])` as you did. The later does an extra unnecessary conversion.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you:

```
$(".short").each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
})


$(".short").each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
})
```

Comment: The OP is using jQuery UI. Using `.button( "option", "label" )` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `innerText` property which *Sets or retrieves the text between the start and end tags of the object.*

So try this .

```
var all_short_btns = $(".Short");
for(i=0; i< all_short_btns.length; i++){
   alert(all_short_btns[i].innerText);
}
```

Alternatively you can also use `eq(i)` to get it.

```
for(i=0; i< all_short_btns.length; i++){
   alert(all_short_btns.eq(i).html());
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/25eWd/1/)

Comment: The OP uses jQuery UI. Using `.button( "option", "label" )` is perfectly fine, if called on a jQuery object of course. Note that `.innerText` is not supported in Firefox (it's `.textContent` there).

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling I have updated my answer for that option as well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you, I found this is also working:-

```
alert(all_short_btns.eq(i).button( "option", "label" ));
```

Comment: Your answer was given before you have identified. why you are not considering to accept them.

Comment: @silentboy: Everyone else suggested to use `.text` or `.html` instead of `.button( "option", "label" )`, so it is *not* the same answer. And why do you assume the OP does not intend to accept one of the other answers? They still have to wait a couple of minutes before they can.

Comment: I am not able to accept the answer after 10mints of the question is asked. Till then I need to wait. Ofcourse I shall accept one of the answers because of the answers given below I was able to find my way.

Comment: @silentboy: With the help of these answers only I have Identified my answers. So I just want to share it. And see now after 10mints I have accepted the answer which seems best to me..

Comment: great, i think giving feedback is a good thing. +1 for your question